# Rclone and Google Drive Authorization giving an error

Tags: 22.04, headless, google-drive, rclone

I'm running a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS public server. I'm attempting to install Rclone to back up a folder to my Google Drive. I'm using the notes from where I did this before but I cannot get it to work this time.

I've installed Rclone and then ran the `rclone config` to set it up with Google.

Here is what I was prompted with:

```
# rclone config
2024/01/22 19:29:43 NOTICE: Config file "/root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found - using defaults
No remotes found - make a new one
n) New remote
s) Set configuration password
q) Quit config
n/s/q> n
name> google-drive
Type of storage to configure.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
 1 / 1Fichier
   \ "fichier"
 2 / Alias for an existing remote
   \ "alias"
 3 / Amazon Drive
   \ "amazon cloud drive"
 4 / Amazon S3 Compliant Storage Provider (AWS, Alibaba, Ceph, Digital Ocean, Dreamhost, IBM COS, Minio, Tencent COS, etc)
   \ "s3"
 5 / Backblaze B2
   \ "b2"
 6 / Box
   \ "box"
 7 / Cache a remote
   \ "cache"
 8 / Citrix Sharefile
   \ "sharefile"
 9 / Dropbox
   \ "dropbox"
10 / Encrypt/Decrypt a remote
   \ "crypt"
11 / FTP Connection
   \ "ftp"
12 / Google Cloud Storage (this is not Google Drive)
   \ "google cloud storage"
13 / Google Drive
   \ "drive"
14 / Google Photos
   \ "google photos"
15 / Hubic
   \ "hubic"
16 / In memory object storage system.
   \ "memory"
17 / Jottacloud
   \ "jottacloud"
18 / Koofr
   \ "koofr"
19 / Local Disk
   \ "local"
20 / Mail.ru Cloud
   \ "mailru"
21 / Microsoft Azure Blob Storage
   \ "azureblob"
22 / Microsoft OneDrive
   \ "onedrive"
23 / OpenDrive
   \ "opendrive"
24 / OpenStack Swift (Rackspace Cloud Files, Memset Memstore, OVH)
   \ "swift"
25 / Pcloud
   \ "pcloud"
26 / Put.io
   \ "putio"
27 / SSH/SFTP Connection
   \ "sftp"
28 / Sugarsync
   \ "sugarsync"
29 / Transparently chunk/split large files
   \ "chunker"
30 / Union merges the contents of several upstream fs
   \ "union"
31 / Webdav
   \ "webdav"
32 / Yandex Disk
   \ "yandex"
33 / http Connection
   \ "http"
34 / premiumize.me
   \ "premiumizeme"
35 / seafile
   \ "seafile"
Storage> 13
** See help for drive backend at: https://rclone.org/drive/ **

Google Application Client Id
Setting your own is recommended.
See https://rclone.org/drive/#making-your-own-client-id for how to create your own.
If you leave this blank, it will use an internal key which is low performance.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
client_id>
OAuth Client Secret
Leave blank normally.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
client_secret>
Scope that rclone should use when requesting access from drive.
Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
 1 / Full access all files, excluding Application Data Folder.
   \ "drive"
 2 / Read-only access to file metadata and file contents.
   \ "drive.readonly"
   / Access to files created by rclone only.
 3 | These are visible in the drive website.
   | File authorization is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.
   \ "drive.file"
   / Allows read and write access to the Application Data folder.
 4 | This is not visible in the drive website.
   \ "drive.appfolder"
   / Allows read-only access to file metadata but
 5 | does not allow any access to read or download file content.
   \ "drive.metadata.readonly"
scope> 1
ID of the root folder
Leave blank normally.

Fill in to access "Computers" folders (see docs), or for rclone to use
a non root folder as its starting point.

Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
root_folder_id>
Service Account Credentials JSON file path
Leave blank normally.
Needed only if you want use SA instead of interactive login.

Leading `~` will be expanded in the file name as will environment variables such as `${RCLONE_CONFIG_DIR}`.

Enter a string value. Press Enter for the default ("").
service_account_file>
Edit advanced config? (y/n)
y) Yes
n) No (default)
y/n> n

Remote config
Use auto config?
 * Say Y if not sure
 * Say N if you are working on a remote or headless machine
y) Yes (default)
n) No
y/n> n
Please go to the following link: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&state=PWUG9PLt1
Log in and authorize rclone for access
Enter verification code>
```

If I enter in my own credentials or use the default, I'm getting the same error:

[image]

What I've tried:

1. Enter in an api key AND using the default.
2. Restarted the server.
3. Recreated the credentials.

When I ran these steps previously, it was from Ubuntu 22.04 Workstation and I was able to authenticate the api through the browser. I'm not able to do that this time on a headless server.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install rclone from the standard Ubuntu repositories? From rclone's site: "The distributed versions of rclone are often quite out of date and for this reason we recommend one of the other installation methods if possible." The 22.04 repos include rclone 1.53.3, while the latest version is 1.65.1. The latest version can most easily be installed using snap. Can you try on the latest version, following the directions here (https://rclone.org/drive/) and see if that works?

Comment: @johnandmegh You are awesome. That was it. Once I updated, it started working. Tyvm!!!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked - posting in an "answer" format for others to be able to find more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur when using the rclone version in the standard Ubuntu repositories (".deb packages"), which is updated much less frequently than the upstream software and therefore isn't current with changes made by upstream developers to adapt to the different cloud services' API requirements.

The easiest way to get an up-to-date version of rclone on Ubuntu is via the community-maintained snap:

`sudo snap install rclone`

After which, you can then follow the direction on rclone's Google Drive page to setup: https://rclone.org/drive/